# Slow performance with SQL Compact Server Tool 3.5 SP1

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to deploy a .Net Compact Framework app that uses a local SQL Server Compact database that is replicated to a SQL Server 2005 SP3 database to our test environment.

In our Development environment using ActiveSync we can initialise the 40mb database simply and easily. However, in our testing environment the server is only sending 1-2K per second and our initialisation times out.

We use Avalanche to deploy in the testing environment and place the Motorolla MC75 device into a cradle to start the syncronisation.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that we had defined our own RowGUIDs on the replicated tables which had a default constraint of GetID(). By changing this to be GetNextSequentialID() our performance suddenly dropped from 10 hours+ to around 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Windows 2003 Service pack 2 ? It enable by default network offload, which cause issue if the network driver is too old. Since, another hotfix disable this network offload by default.

[Some problems occur after installing Windows Server 2003 SP2](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B945977&x=20&y=11)

==> it specify SQL network problem related to this network offload.

Also check for:

- Antivirus / firewall
- Network problem (duplex mismatch...)